# Skype connection refused in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python, skype

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Skype for Linux 4.3. I also installed the Skype4Py library/package.

When I run the program, skype app is getting launched, but after that nothing is happening. 
Below is the error I get.

```
Ubuntu:~/Skype4Py/examples$ ./search.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "./search.py", line 18, in <module>     
skype.Attach()   
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Skype4Py/skype.py", line 408, in Attach   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Skype4Py/api/posix_dbus.py", line 164, in attach
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Skype4Py/api/__init__.py", line 163, in set_attachment_status
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Skype4Py/skype.py", line 35, in attachment_changed
Skype4Py.errors.SkypeAPIError: Skype connection refused
```

Comment: I don't think Skype 4.3 is still supported by Skype. You need to switch to the new version.

Comment: Skype 4.3 is no more operational as per MS update. You have to switch to 8.x version to get it operational. And right now new version of Skype only supported in 64bit operating systems.

Comment: @Rooney That answers the question, do you mind adding it as an answer?

Comment: i have changed skype to "Skype Version: 8.11.0.4". This is the latest version. but i still get the same error.

Comment: Please download the `.deb` file from skype.com and install it using `dpkg -i` command. Once installed you can run it by typing `skypeforlinux` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Skype 4.3 is no more operational as per Microsoft update. You have to switch to 8.x version to get it operational. And right now new version of Skype only supported in 64bit operating systems.

You can download the new version of Skype from https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/

Comment: Hi Rooney, I have installed the newer version of skype "Skype Version: 8.11.0.4". I have also removed the 4.3 version. But still errors are persisting. can u guide me in installing the Skype4Py again?

Comment: i have changed skype to "Skype Version: 8.11.0.4". This is the latest version. but i still get the same error.  can u guide me in installing the Skype4Py library/Package in ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I wouldn't expected something that hasn't been updated for years to work with the current version.